# pip не может поставить python-magic

Tags: python, pip, mime

**pip 20.0.1, setuptools 41.2.0**

**Эта проблема только на винде. Изначально писал на линухе и в виртуале всё подтягивалось и запускалось**

**setup.py**

```
install_requires=['bs4',
                      'lxml',
                      'WeasyPrint',
                      'yattag',
                      'EbookLib',
                      'colorama',
                      'requests',
                      'python-magic'],
```

Используя **virtualenv** и запуская `pip install .` рядом с **setup.py** всё скачивает вроде нормально. При запуске получаю

```
 File "c:\users\1337k\pycharmprojects\untitled1\v2\lib\site-packages\rss_reader\converting.py", line 3, in <module>
    import magic
  File "c:\users\1337k\pycharmprojects\untitled1\v2\lib\site-packages\magic.py", line 181, in <module>
    raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation
```

Прогуглил, вроде проблема решается с помощью **python-magic-bin**
Делаю `pip install python-magic-bin`

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin`
```

или

```
pip uninstall python-magic
pip install python-magic-bin

 -> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin
```

или

```
pip uninstall python-magic
pip install python-magic-bin==0.4.14

-> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin==0.4.14 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin==0.4.14
```

**А может просто** `pip install libmagic
rss-reader`(название модуля)?

```
-> pip install libmagic
Processing c:\users\1337k\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\68\33\a4\a404635e64d223a77f925132e51c1ccfdc32fd01d66b338f1a\libmagic-1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: libmagic
Successfully installed libmagic-1.0
(v2) PS C:\Users\1337k\PycharmProjects\untitled1> rss-reader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\1337k\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\1337k\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\1337k\PycharmProjects\untitled1\v2\Scripts\rss-reader.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\1337k\pycharmprojects\untitled1\v2\lib\site-packages\rss_reader\__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rss_reader import converting
  File "c:\users\1337k\pycharmprojects\untitled1\v2\lib\site-packages\rss_reader\converting.py", line 3, in <module>
    import magic
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magic'
```

**P.S.**

не хочется лишаться зависимости от magic, тк я просто поправлял зависимости старого проекта и код переписывать не хочется

**P.S.2**

если кто-то может предложить нормальную замену, то прошу [сюда](https://github.com/Kwizchm/PythonHomework/blob/5abc491e9711f4c488a944f6ba535c2bf325dd89/rss_reader/converting.py#L147). Важно, что бы тип определялся из битов, полученных от requests.get

Comment: Попробуйте вручную скачать файлы и установить их

Comment: `python-magic-bin` отлично устанавливается на `python 3.7`, но если судить по [страничке проекта](https://github.com/julian-r/python-magic), то поддержки под 3.8 ещё нет. Тогда как для `python-magic` она есть.

Comment: @Jazzis только что переставил пайтон на 3.7.5. Точно так же не видит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [страничке проекта](https://github.com/julian-r/python-magic), вам нужно:

1. Скачать архивы `Binaries` и `Dependencies` из проекта [File for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).
2. Из них скопировать `magic1.dll`, `regex2.dll` и `zlib1.dll` куда-нибудь и указать их в вашем `PATH`.
3. Вручную из исходников установить `python-magic-bin`.
4. Скопировать из архива `Binaries` файл `magic` по пути `share\misc` и указать его в `Magic(magic_file=...)`.

Взято со страниц библиотек [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) (раздел Installation > Windows) и [python-magic-bin](https://github.com/julian-r/python-magic) (раздел Installation > Dependencies).

Comment: Это в setup.py можно как-то отпразить?